Trouble Triggering Serialization Error with PostgreSQL Trigger Function
I'm encountering a puzzling issue with PostgreSQL's SERIALIZABLE isolation level and a trigger function's behavior. I have one table, and a trigger:
-- Definition of the events table
CREATE TABLE events (
    version INTEGER NOT NULL,
    id VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT events_pk PRIMARY KEY (id, version)
);

-- Trigger function definition
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ensure_next_version_is_higher()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    -- Allow version 1 to be inserted without any checks
    IF NEW.version = 1 THEN
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;

    -- Check if the new version is exactly one higher than the maximum version
    IF NEW.version = (SELECT MAX(version) + 1 FROM events WHERE id = NEW.id) THEN
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSE
        -- If the new version is not exactly one higher than the maximum version, raise an exception
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'The new version is not exactly one higher than the maximum version.';
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Trigger definition
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_check_version
BEFORE INSERT ON events
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION ensure_next_version_is_higher();

Now, when I run two transactions with serializable isolation, where one checks for the existence of the parent record, and then decides to proceed or not, and the other inserts a new version of the parent record, I would expect those to be in conflict as the trigger queries the maximum version as well:
Here's the scenario:
Transaction 1:
BEGIN;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
SELECT * FROM events WHERE id = 'parent' AND version >= (SELECT MAX(version) FROM events WHERE id = 'parent');
-- If parent existed, then do:
INSERT INTO events (version, id) VALUES (1, 'child5');
-- pause here while transaction 2 is executed and committed
COMMIT;

Transaction 2:
-- assuming that there already is a parent record with version 1 and 2:
BEGIN;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
-- SELECT MAX(version) FROM events WHERE id = 'parent';
INSERT INTO events (version, id) VALUES (3, 'parent');
COMMIT;

The above does not trigger a serialization error for Transaction 1.
Interestingly, if I uncomment the line in Transaction 2 to manually select the maximum version before the insert, I do get the expected serialization error in Transaction 1.
I'm a bit at a loss why the trigger would not cause the same error.

If you run the first transaction strictly before the second one, is the result the same? If yes, they are serializable.
